# Split long column heading but centre column entries

Tags: tabularx, columns, justification

I have a table in which one column heading is long so it needs to be broken over several lines. When I try to do that the entries in the column, which are all very short (in fact they are single characters), are all left justified. That looks odd.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
 \begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering  
    \caption{ } 
        \def\tabularxcolumn#1{m{#1}}
        \begin{tabularx}{0.5\textwidth}{cc p{0.23\linewidth}}
        \toprule
         {A} & {B}& {Blah blah longword shortword}\\
        Moon& Earth& 3 \\ 
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

That code gives the following result:
[image]

How can I centre the entries without stretching out the column heading?

Comment: Take a look at the makecell package.

Comment: Unrelated: there is no point in using `tabularx` without the `X` column.

Comment: 1. With `tabularx`,  you need to have at least one X column. I suggest using this preamble for your table: `{cc>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are three different ways to get a linebreak inside of a lenghty column header while keeping the contents of the column horizontally centered:

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}
\begin{document}

 \begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering  
    \caption{Regular tabular with makecell's thead command, manual linebreak} 
        \begin{tabular}{ccc}
        \toprule
         \thead{A} & \thead{B}&\thead {Blah blah longword\\ shortword}\\
        Moon& Earth& 3 \\ 
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

 \begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering  
    \caption{Regular tabular and centered m type column, automatic line break} 
        \begin{tabular}{cc >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.23\linewidth}}
        \toprule
         {A} & {B}& {Blah blah longword shortword}\\
        Moon& Earth& 3 \\ 
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

 \begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering  
    \caption{Tabularx and centered X type column, automatic line break} 
        \renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
        \begin{tabularx}{0.5\textwidth}{cc >{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
        \toprule
         {A} & {B}& {Blah blah longword shortword}\\
        Moon& Earth& 3 \\ 
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

Left aligned column headers:

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}
\begin{document}

 \begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering  
    \caption{Regular tabular with makecell's thead command, manual linebreak} 
        \begin{tabular}{ccc}
        \toprule
         \thead{A} & \thead{B}&\thead[l]{Blah blah longword\\ shortword}\\
        Moon& Earth& 3 \\ 
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

 \begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering  
    \caption{Regular tabular and centered m type column, automatic line break} 
        \begin{tabular}{ccc}
        \toprule
         {A} & {B}& \multicolumn{1}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{0.25\linewidth}}{Blah blah longword shortword}\\
        Moon& Earth& 3 \\ 
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That is really helpful. Am I right in seeing in each case that the heading is centred in its (multilined) cell? If I wanted that text to be left justified but with the entires underneath still centred, could that be done?

Comment: @JeremyC: I updated my answer and added two example that show how you could achive vertically centered, left aligned column headers with linebreaks inside of an otehrwise horizontally centered column.